# A 'select-and-transform' XML transformation language?

Tags: scripting, xslt

I would like to write XML document transformations as one-time commands and in standalone scripts, the same way that I use Unix tools such as `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, etcetera, to manipulate text files.  The scripts must be portable between Linux and Windows (using Cygwin is OK).

If you *already do this* on a regular basis, what solution do you use?  Can you recommend it?

(Some background:

Right now, I want to remove a certain kind of element from a set of XML documents.
I frequently need to do this kind of systematic XML document rewriting; 
Sometimes, on the fly (on the command line, which I use a lot);
more often, I want to build more complex transformations, save them to file, and execute them from the file.

So I want an XML transformation scripting language that can be used on the command line. 
Something like `sed` or `awk` for XML documents: its commands would specify a selector that selects nodes in the input document, plus an operation that specifies what to do with the document at each selected node.

Often, I chicken out and write a Perl script with [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::LibXML).
This works, but it really doesn't fit the bill:

- syntactically: the code is far too verbose to be used on the command line
- semantically: the 'select and transform' pattern isn't given, I have to explicitly program this behavior into my code, so it is unnecessarily difficult for readers to understand that that is what is really happening
- syntactically/semantically: reading or writing this code requires general fluency in the language

The same can be said for using any other general-purpose programming language.

Well, this was what XSLT was invented for, right?

Maybe; [I can use XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391038/remove-elements-from-xml), but it really suffers from the same drawbacks.

A better match is [xmlstarlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135241/selecting-elements-from-xml-file-with-xmlstarlet-cant-quite-get-the-syntax-rig): it really is like `sed`, in that it supports short, cryptic commands of the type I want.  However, just like with sed, larger programs composed from these commands are difficult to understand.

Another idea is to use [jQuery DOM manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/):

- much more powerful selectors than XPath
- elegant and compact ways to combine selection and operation
- built-in extensibility with arbitrary JavaScript functions (but doesn't *require* much JavaScript knowledge for simple cases)

Great, but I'll need a utility that allows me to use such expressions as standalone scripts:

```
jqmanip --html '$(a:parent).detach()' foo.html > bar.html
jqmanip convert-tables-to-divs.jqm foo.html > bar.html
```

That is the sort of utility I'm looking for.)

Comment: Update: I just discovered another such language: [XDT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Right now I'm using a combination of `/bin/sh` and `xmlstarlet`, e..g.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# csproj2csproj - clean up VS 2010/2012 C# project files in various ways
#
# $Id$

dft='//*[local-name()="PropertyGroup" and not(@Condition)]'
dbg='//*[local-name()="PropertyGroup" and contains(*/@Condition,"Debug")]'
rel='//*[local-name()="PropertyGroup" and contains(*/@Condition,"Release")]'

RemoveTree()
{
  xmlstarlet ed -d "$1"
}

AppendAsLastChild()
{
  xmlstarlet ed -i "$1"'/*[last()]' -t elem -n "$2" -v "$3"
}

sed 's/encoding="utf-8"/encoding="Windows-1252"/' "$@" |
RemoveTree '//*[@Include="My Project\"]' |
RemoveTree '//*[not(@*|*) and not(normalize-space(.))]' |
RemoveTree '//*[local-name()="LangVersion"]' |
RemoveTree '//*[local-name()="CheckForOverFlowUnderFlow"]' |
RemoveTree '//*[local-name()="DocumentationFile"]' |
AppendAsLastChild "$dft" LangVersion ISO-2 |
AppendAsLastChild "$dbg" CheckForOverflowUnderflow true |
AppendAsLastChild "$rel" CheckForOverflowUnderflow false |
AppendAsLastChild "$rel" DocumentationFile 'bin\Release\vsdocs.xml'
```